# Draw a bitmap from URL based on a true/false condition

Tags: java, android

With the following code I want to display a image only if `chatMessageObj.left` is true, but the image aways shows up.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

...

String personPhotoUrl = "Image url";
personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0, personPhotoUrl.length() - 2) + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;
    if (chatMessageObj.left) {
        new LoadProfileImage(chatImage).execute(personPhotoUrl);
    }

...

}

private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;

    public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

I need somenthig like this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result, boolean display) {
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(display ? result : null);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm assuming that if chatMessageObj.left is not true, then you don't want to execute the Asynctask? if so, then what you have provided here looks correct. you need to check the value or how chatMessageObj.left is assigned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because listview always keep refreshing, so what you need to do is to just add else block,

Something like this,

```
if (chatMessageObj.left) {
    new LoadProfileImage(chatImage).execute(personPhotoUrl);
} else {
    chatImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Hopefully this helps you :)